# Issue with loop and nested if statements

Tags: lua

```
motor = peripheral.wrap("right")

repeat 


RPM = motor.getSpeed()
print("current rpm is ", RPM, "RPM. What RPM do you need?")
setrpm = tonumber(io.read())
if type(setrpm) == "number"
    then
        motor.setSpeed(setrpm)
        goto contine

    else 
        print("Must be a number between -256 and 256")
        print("current rpm is ", RPM, "RPM. What RPM do you need?")
        setrpm = tonumber(io.read())
        end
::continue::

rpm = motor.getSpeed()
su =  ( rpm * 16)
fe = motor.getEnergyConsumption()
print("You have set speed " , rpm, " RPM")
print("Current stress cap is now ", su, "SU")
print("Power Consumption is now ", fe, "FE/t")

until( fe > 100 )
end
```

Expected behavor
loop until fe=100 or more

current behavor
motor.lua:12 '=' expected near 'continue'

writing a loop of code in computercraft to ask what rpm a block needs to spin at, expected behavor is to keep looping the code endlessly till the FE>100 (for the block its looking at its imposible)

Comment: you have an extra end, and you typoed `continue` in the `goto` statement, also most importantly that `goto` does absolutely nothing and using `goto` in general is a code smell.

Comment: It looks like you are using Lua 5.1, there is no `goto` operator in this Lua version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computercraft uses Lua 5.1. `goto` was introduced in Lua 5.2 so you cannot use it in your script.

That aside there is no point in using it like that.

```
if condition then
  -- block A
else
  -- block B
end
```

After executing block A or B Lua will automatically continue after the `end`.
You don't have to explicitly tell Lua to do that.

In a repeat until statement there is no `end` after the condition. The correct syntax is:

```
repeat block until exp
```

Befor posting your problems here, at least check for typos. `contine` is not the label you intended to go to.

Please refer to https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html